# How to bind Parent UserControl Dependency Property to the Child UserControl ViewModel Property?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, binding

Hi I have 2 UserControls. Parent UserControl and Child UserControl and both have their own ViewModel. How can I bind Parent Control's Dependency Property to the Property in the ViewModel of Child Control. Any help will be appericiable. I can easily bind the Parent UserControl DependencyProperty to the Child Control Dependency Property . But the problem is how to bind it to ViewModel Property. Suppose I bind Tag Property of Child UserControl to the Dependency Property of ParentControl(upto here its fine) but now how I can Bind this Tag Property to the ViewModel Property.(I want to keep it simple and don't want to use Converter/Converter Parameter logic).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically your `ViewModels` are the `DataContext` (Data Layer) of your `UserControls`, so you can access the `ViewModel` of the child control by binding to the `DataContext` property

```
{Binding ElementName=MyChildUserControl, Path=DataContext.ChildViewModelProperty}
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
{Binding Path=PathToParentDP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ParentType}}}
```

Comment: Thanks ,yes it works fine , I bind the above binding to the Dependency property of ChildControl , But then how I can bind the Child Control this Dependecy Property to ViewModel Property as we cant do binding/assign value Same Property twice.